# EmberJS testing: target id created from each loop

Tags: ember.js

I used an each loop to create a unique id for every input that's created. Ex: `id='amount0'`, `id='amount1'`, etc.. but I can't target them during testing, it says the element is not found.

Error

```
Promise rejected during "Amount input works": Element not found when calling `fillIn('#amount0')`.
```

HBS file:

```
{{#each userInfo as |user index|}}
<p output-test-info>
    <button onclick={{action clearEverything index}}>-</button>
    {{user.name}}
    <input id="amount{{index}}" onchange={{action (action addAmount index) value="target.value"}}>
</p>
{{/each}}
```

Test file:

```
test('Amount input works', async function(assert){
    const itemList = document.queryCommandValue('output-test-info');
    this.set('tempName', [{name: 'bobby'}, {name: 'peter'}]);
    this.set('tempAct', [{activity: 'dinner'}, {activity: 'movies'}])
    await render(hbs`<Output @userinfo={{this.tempArray}} @userAct={{this.tempAct}}/>`);

    await fillIn('#amount0', '20');
  })
```

Comment: a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/) reproduction would be helpful to debug.

Answer (score 0):

The error apparently is here `@userinfo={{this.tempArray}}`. You don't have this variable, you have only `tempName` and `tempAct`. Most likely the `tempName` was meant there.

Comment: Oh, nice catch but that wasn't the problem :/ it does look like nothing is being passed in tho